# frame by frame animation in windows store app flickers

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone, windows-store-apps

I want to implement frame by frame animation in my windows store app for which i used this code:

```
void moving_objects(DependencyObject obj_name, string img_path, int no_of_frames, int time_to_play)
{

   var animation = new ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames();
   framestory = new Storyboard();


   Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, obj_name);
   Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, "Source");

   framestory.Children.Add(animation);

   for (int i = 1; i <= no_of_frames; i++)
   {
      // MessageBox.Show(img_path + i + ".png");
      var keyframe = new DiscreteObjectKeyFrame
      {
          KeyTime = KeyTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(time_to_play * i)),
          Value = new BitmapImage(new Uri(this.BaseUri, img_path + i + ".png")),
      };

      animation.KeyFrames.Add(keyframe);

   }

   framestory.Begin();


}
```

and i call this method on image tapped like this:

```
moving_objects(DogImage, "/Assets/Images/Dog/d", 12, 150);
```

this code works fine in windows phone app but for store app the animation flickers i.e the images take time to load.how can i solve this problem?

Comment: It seems to me like it's likely the file IO that is causing the delay. I suggest trying reading the .png files into memory prior to the animation, possibly storing them in a `Dictionary<string, BitmapImage>`. You may also be able to simply call them previously and see if the system caching stores them for you.

Comment: yes this solved the problem when i used this with timer but with storyboard again it flickers.

Comment: this does not work with large size images